# Is it possible to split public methods in categories?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Right now I want to split my ViewController, containing public methods, into several files for easier management and navigation. I know that categories can do this, but it's largely used by importing the categories each and everytime you want to use them. The ViewController I'm working on is meant to be subclassed A LOT of times, so that's not really an option.

What I want to achieve is splitting those public methods into categories and combine all those categories into one file, importing them in the header file to ensure that subclasses do not need to import them again and again.

Is there a way to do this? I searched around, but all that I've found is:

1. Declare the categories in one same header, declare them in multiple implementation file
   This is not what I'm looking for, because I heavily document my code inline to take advantage of XCode 5's ability to display inline documents. Navigating the class **without** using Ctrl+6 is already a nightmare labyrinth due to all the documentation. It will alleviate the problem with implementation file, but not what I'm looking for.
2. Declare the categories in split headers
   All that I've found regarding this are for private uses in that class only (import the categories in the implementation file). I need to split the public methods as well and have them available for subclasses to see.

I thought about creating a class that imports all the categories, essentially hiding the actual class, but that locks me out from protected variables (and I need those).

Is there a... solution to this, or is this really that impossible with the current Objective C?

EDIT:
I've heard that DocSets is the way Apple go to allow them to display documentation without documenting the code inline. If using DocSet allows me to clean up my header code (that is, move the documentation elsewhere) and still have the documentation available in Quick Help, I'd like to learn that

Comment: You may be better server explaining why you have so many subclasses - it may well be better to change your approach at a higher level...

Comment: @Wain Each subclass is their own page. The pages all have similar needs, so I group those needs into one ViewController and simply create each page by subclassing the base ViewController and modify each page (subclass) individually for their own specific needs

Comment: You can have an "umbrella" .h file that imports the class header together with all (public) category headers, i.e. your #2 should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just split the implementation file. Restructuring the class for multiple headers took longer and is harder than I expected. I think the scenario that I posted cannot be solved in the way that I wanted it to be.

Answer (score 1):

In these circumstances, I would import the necessary categories on the .h of the parent class, this way the subclasses get the categories as well.

Comment: The problem is, if I include the headers on the .h of the parent class, it constitutes circular reference (categories imports the main class, main class imports categories) and I can't use it, I tried

Answer (score 1):

Declare your categories in separate header files. Write another header file whose sole purpose is to #include each of the category headers that has public API. Use that single header file when writing subclasses. Write yet another header file that includes the single public file and any additional private category headers, for your internal use.

This is similar to what frameworks do with their classes. Foundation's classes are declared in separate files NSObject.h, NSArray.h, etc. Then Foundation/Foundation.h includes each of the headers for public classes.

Comment: Foundation is a collection of individual classes, the categories are part of the same entity. Since the original class uses protected variables, doing what you suggested requires me to implement the original class as a different entity than the one being subclassed and the originally protected variables will have to be implemented as public properties, I don't mean to do that